# Automatical generation of a property based on other properties in Foundry Ontology Object actions

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop

While relying on embedded Object Ontology's actions, I wanted to create an action that performs the following:

- Create a new object (via a form) prompting
- Uses the form data to generate new property based on some of the properties manually assigned
- Updates the object

My target here is to prompt the user to manually input some attributes of the new object, which will actually form the "Description property" (i.e. the concatenation of some of the attributes assigned).

I expected being able to contextually use the "Run function" calling an externally defined ts function, but this is disabled.

What can be a correct workaround?

Comment: Using a Typescript Function and creating a function-backed action would be the correct pattern here. If you're finding that this is blocked or disabled in some way, I'd recommend getting in touch with someone from the Foundry support team for your org to figure that out as there isn't a reason it shouldn't be available.

Comment: Realizing that your issue is probably that you first had a "Create Object" rule and _then_ were trying to add an additional "Run function" rule. You can only use "Run function" by itself, so you'd need to do both the object creation and the property updates in a single function (which is quite straightforward and covered in the Actions/Functions docs).